# how to remove recovery mode screen in Raspberry pi 3 b+

Tags: recovery

Any body can help me about recovery mode.
How to remove recovery mode screen in Raspberry pi 3 b+

Thanks

Comment: Rewrite your SDCard with RaspiOS32 rather than NOOBS. NOOBS is past its use-by date. Get the Raspberry Pi Imager (aka RPImager) from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ to reformat, download RaspiOS and re-write your SDCard in a single simple operation.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your SDCard with RaspiOS32 rather than NOOBS. NOOBS is past its use-by date. Get the Raspberry Pi Imager (aka RPImager) from https://raspberrypi.org/downloads to reformat, download RaspiOS and re-write your SDCard in a single simple operation.